# admin-on-rest CreateButton doesn't pass record id of form

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am using ReferenceManyField to show the items in an order, the typical master/detail database pattern. I am able to edit existing detail records, but can't find a way to add new detail records. I tried the following, but doesn't receive {id} like does. I notice that admin-on-rest-demo allows editing of detail records (reviews of products), but does not allow adding of reviews. Is there a pattern or workaround to do this?

```
   <SimpleForm>
        <ReferenceManyField label="ITEMS" reference="orderitems" target="orderId">
            <Datagrid>
                // fields removed for clarity...
                <CreateButton/> <===== does not pass {id} of form record
                <EditButton/>    <===== passes {id} of form record
            </Datagrid>
        </ReferenceManyField>
    </SimpleForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1402):

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pp0o4x40p0

The relevant code parts are:

- the `CreateCommentButton` component inside `src/posts.js`
- the `CommentCreate` component inside `src/comments.js` (note how we set the `defaultValue` prop on `SimpleForm`)